# Помогите! Проблемы с GRUB. Не видит винду, долго загружается

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, grub, bios

Установил недавно ubuntu рядом с windows 10. Вроде всё ок, но..
При включении пк сразу запускается ubuntu. А чтобы запустить винду нужно заходить в биос и менять приоритет загрузки. Я покопался в интернете "повводил" всякие команды по типу таких
`grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /boot/*/*/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`
`sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mtn`
`sudo update-grub`
Особо не разбираясь, что это всё делает
(винда установлена на nvme0n1p3, диск D от винды - sdb, диск с линуксом - sda. То есть системы на разных дисках. И да, винда работает, через биос в нее можно загрузиться)

После всяких процедур груб появляться не стал. Потом мне посоветовали нажимать шифт при запуске.
После этого граб запустился. Но винды там не было (наверное, по-этому он сам и не запускается). Из вариантов загрузки - ubuntu и 2 теста памяти

А после этого, всегда при включении пк, после лого биоса появляется граб. Но это просто серый экран с светло-серой рамкой по краям, без всяких пунктов загрузки. Просто серый экран. Причем этот серый экран висит минут 5!

Скорее всего я как-то накосячил с путями, и теперь граб очень долго их ищет, но не находит.

Как починить граб??

Comment: Хотя вот сейчас пк запустил, Получилось зайти в биос, проверил винду. Загрузился обратно на линукс. После заставки биоса - граб (просто серый экран с серой рамкой, надписей нет) - далее уже убунту сам

Comment: Блин, он пару раз нормально запускается. А потом опять зависает минут на 5 на заставке Биоса! После заставки граб с пунктами : убунту, тест памяти 1, тест памяти 2